# All pages in Google Chrome are rendered with a very thin, bad looking serif font

Tags: google-chrome, font

In every later release of Google Chrome (including the just released version 11), all pages are rendered with a very thin, jaggy serif font.

This is how it looks in Chrome 11:

[image: google mail in chrome 11]

And here is Safari 5.0.5:

[image]

The picture might be too small to really show how bad the serif font is, but on-screen it's horrible.

There's no difference if I try to edit the font settings in Chrome. It's always the same font. I've also — of course — tried to remove and re-install Chrome, multiple times. Have tried to remove everything Chrome-related from $HOME/Library (Application Support, Caches etc). No change in behavior.

Here is an example of my font settings, but as I said, the font is always the same — on all pages — regardless of what I set in the font settings. I can set it to Helvetica and it's still a jaggy, horrible, small serif:

[image]

So, what do I do? Suggestions?

Comment: I think this might be a consequence of font smoothing.

Comment: I don't think so. It's always the same font, in all pages and no matter what I try to change to Chrome font settings to. It's not a subtle difference in smoothing or anti-aliasing, it just looks horrible.

Comment: When (which version of Chrome) did it started to happen? I've not update to Chrome 11 yet, but I never had those issues with 10-. You tagged the question [gmail]. Does it only happens in gmail or every site?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html Check this out, it looks very much like font rendering differences. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html also talks about it. However looking at my chrome and my safari I dont see it. This is weird.

Comment: I have Chrome 11.0.696.57 and I don't see the issue. This is likely a CSS being cached somewhere and failing to load (I have a similar issue every now and then, where chrome acts weird, but I usually close it and open it to fix it).

Comment: I've noticed it from Chrome 10 and it's on all webbpages, not just Google Apps sites.

Comment: I don't think that there could be a css caching problem. I've "rm -rf":ed all Google caches under $HOME/Library.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your font settings?

Comment: @hobs font rendering does not change the font family. Differences are in pixel-level and the underlying font is always the same. In this case Chrome 11 clearly has a serif font and Safari has a sans-serif font; see also the full-sized screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/JRbdW.png

Comment: If reseting the fonts back to default don't do anything, I would suggest just uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome. Serif fonts are not the default, that's for sure.

Comment: I've re-installed Chrome many many times and it doesn't help. As I've also already said, I also have cleaned out all caches (and similar stuff) manually after uninstalling. No change in behavior. A newly installed Chrome always show that horrible serif font.

Comment: Have you gone to a webpage that uses embedded fonts? Like [lanyrd.com](http://lanyrd.com)?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling chrome with something like appcleaner (http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/) to completely remove chrome?

Comment: @Erik I'd be interested in knowing if you've correctly removed all caches. You mention doing things in $HOME/Library (Application Support, Caches etc), but why don't you just use an utility like Onyx (http://www.titanium.free.fr/) just to make sure?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about atsutil et al, so when I said I'd removed all caches, I meant I physically removed caches, everything related to chrome etc etc, in $HOME/Library. But atsutil solved the whole issue so I'm now a happy camper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go blocking fonts and so on, first check this page:
http://www.google.com/webfonts

How you get rendered the fonts? On my chrome - without any problems, the chrome CAN render different fonts.

You can try these commands from the Terminal.app

```
sudo atsutil databases -remove
sudo atsutil server -shutdown
sudo atsutil server -ping
```

the above will remove your font cache. Work only in snow leopard!

Comment: Fantastic! This solved the whole problem for me! Great. Many thanks!

Comment: wow, thanx for the points. :)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is ignoring the website font rules and displaying everything in Times New Roman.

Other people have encountered this same issue.  You can see the discussion in the Chrome Help forums here:

- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4f199e721223e57e

Here is the suggested fix:

> I use FontExplorerX Pro. I setup a rule for font requests to deny any request from Chrome.
>
> Then I downloaded Onyx and ran the script to clean all font caches. Restarted and now things are normal.

If this works for you, please mark JTWilcox's answer as helpful in the [Chrome forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4f199e721223e57e).

Comment: I didn't use Onyx, but as @jm666's answer basically seem to be the same (clean the font cache) this probably works as well. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

Just increase minimum font size in prefs

Comment: How does this change the sans-serif issue?