# login page font very thin

Tags: font

MacOS Sierra on macbook pro 2015 15'' retina

After upgrading to Sierra the font looks blurry and I tweaked `AppleFontSmoothing` and font looks very thin, then I googled for a solution

`defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO`

and ticked 'Use LCD font smoothing' option in system settings, now everything looks normal again except the font of login menu:

[image: before login]

[image: after login]

as shown in pics the menu bar font looks thin before login but normal after login.

I've tried method in

[All pages in Google Chrome are rendered with a very thin, bad looking serif font](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/all-pages-in-google-chrome-are-rendered-with-a-very-thin-bad-looking-serif-font)

but no luck, hope anyone could help thanks!

Comment: What version of macOS Sierra are you running? Have you updated all the way up to 10.12.6?

Comment: @Monomeeth yes it's 10.12.6

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're modifying two different global settings: `AppleFontSmoothing` and `CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled`.

`AppleFontSmoothing` is an integer, represented from 0-4, whereas `CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled` is boolean. I'd recommend starting by deleting both, both as your user and globally (`sudo`) `defaults delete -g AppleFontSmoothing`; same with `CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled`.

The Menu Bar's process is called SystemUIServer. So you can restart the Menu Bar (see what your tweaks do) with `killall SystemUIServer`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice unfortunately it doesn't work, when I try to delete them it shows `defaults[39882:9257612] 
Domain (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.` and `defaults[39889:9257821] 
Domain (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.` anyway I'll leave it as it is.